# How is CORS protecting the app?

Tags: cors

I am having problems grasping the CORS concept...

The way I see it the same-origin-policy protects the app from making an ajax call to "untrusted domain". So, **mydomain.com** makes an ajax call to **somedomain.com** and the resource JSON/Script will not be retrieved.

I thought this is to protect the web app when some XSS vulnerability is discovered and someone puts that code using the  tag into your page content and now can make ajax calls to other domains. - Am I right?

If I am right then CORS offers no protection because it's the server policy saying that if a request from **mydomain.com** comes to **somedomain.com** it should be allowed. Now, if I am attacking I would add my script and in my server I would set the CORS policy to allow those requests. From what I get CORS can totally bypass the same-origin-policy

:|

**UPDATE:**

Reading a bit more I found answers that claim that CORS is not to protect the **mydomain.com** app, but the **somedomain.com**. Let's say somedomain.com is your bank that offers APIs to make bank transfers. Bank would allow API calls coming from the browser that has their app loaded (the same domain). In their CORS policy they can say that the script coming from **mydomain.com** can call their API's. Note that client's browser can have the  cookies for the bank set nad  that opens the bank to the attack by scripts coming from **mydomain.com**

Answer (score 3):

CORS does not protect the app.

The Same Origin Policy protects the app by preventing other sites from using a logged in user's browser to read data from it.

CORS allows the server to give other sites permission to read that data (for when the information needs to be shared). i.e. CORS is how you say "Do not apply the Same Origin Policy here".

---

> Now, if I am attacking I would add my script and in my server I would set the CORS policy to allow those requests.

No. The server hosting the data has to set CORS headers. You can't give your own script permission to read data from someone else's site.

---

XSS is an unrelated category of security vulnerabilities. CORS and the Same Origin Policy have nothing to do with them.

Comment: The Same Origin Policy protects the app by preventing other sites from using a logged in user's browser to read data from it. - like a malicious script sending the cookie to some other domain?

Comment: It couldn't read the cookie itself. The Same Origin Policy prevents the site from asking the browser to get `http://mybank.com/myaccountdetails/` which would cause the browser to use the cookie it already has to fetch the data, and then to read the returned data.

Comment: Sorry, I was again focusing on the case where the app got attacked and a <script> injected... So, the same-origin blocks scripts from bbb.com to make requests to aaa.com because browser might be logged into aaa.com (browser protecting the aaa.com)... CORS on the other hand impedes the scripts from different domains to access resources on some server for example aws S3 or some APIs?

Comment: If a `<script>` is injected then it is because the site is vulnerable to XSS attacks. The Same Origin Policy does not defend against XSS. XSS is a completely different class of attack to what the Same Origin Policy defends against. CORS doesn't impede anything, it allows a site to exempt itself (or parts of itself) from protection from the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: Thank you so much... I have to get my head around this all now :D

Answer (score -1):

I would like to think of it as something that makes attacking a little more complicated. The idea is to discourage a casual / less skilled hacker from playing around. Something similar to code obfuscation.

Comment: well, I don't think W3C would go through all this just to repel the attack of the amateur attackers :)